# Nginx - https://www not 301 redirecting

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx, redirect, amazon-ec2

I am moving to a new domain and have set up 301 redirects on my ec2 instance.

Currently I have the following:

```
server {
   listen 80;
   server_name olddomain.co.uk;
   return 301 $scheme://www.newdomain.com$request_uri;
}
```

this works fine for [www.olddomain.co.uk](http://www.olddomain.co.uk) and olddomain.co.uk. However it does not work for https://www.olddomain.co.uk

I am wondering how I can make it so the redirect also works with https://www...

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your server isn't listening to `https://` i.e. 443 port. Connection to `https://www.olddomain.co.uk` would simply be refused. Add proper ssl configurations to your nginx file and it should be fine.

```
server {
   listen 80;
   listen 443 ssl;
   server_name olddomain.co.uk;
   return 301 $scheme://www.newdomain.com$request_uri;
}
```

Comment: This was it thank your Rahul

Answer (score 0):

```
server {

    listen 80 default_server;


    server_name _;


    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;

}
```